# the type or namespace "TextFieldParser" could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textfield

I am trying to use TextfieldParser that was found within [Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-file).  I am using VS 2010 and doing this in C#.

I keep on getting "the type or namespace "TextFieldParser" could not be found.."

When I try and add the using line, it will only go using Microsoft.VisualBasic; deep and not using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you type out the fully qualified name?  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`?

Comment: Probably need to add a reference to your project.

Comment: I tried Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser doesn't work.  It then conplaines about fileIO missing.  How do i add the reference?

Comment: I added it as a reference and now it seems to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

In Visual Studio, right click on `References` in the `Solution Explorer` side panel. Click "Add Reference".

In that list be sure to check `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. Hit OK.

Now in the namespace, add `Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`.

That will allow you to use TextFieldParser. For a good, easy example on how to use it, look here: http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/07/whats-a-nice-class-like-textfieldparser-doing-in-a-namespace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For uncompiled files (aspx / ashx), you need to put an reference in the web.config.  (They cannot use the project references.)

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Alternatively for web applications, it would be preferred to put the code in a compiled file (cs/vb) and add a reference to the project.

See this question [microsoft.visualbasic.fileio does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830017/microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-does-not-exist).

Answer (score 0):

Application references are not available to uncompiled files in your application (aspx, ashx).  The reference would need added to the web.config or else the code would need moved to a compiled file (cs/vb).