# How do I parse this CSV file since it has to many commas in it has like 3 parts I need to retrive information?

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

I am practicing to parse text and csv files. I have a particular csv file on witch I have been trying to parse for several hours, but I have unable to find the correct logic to do so since, according to the parsing 19 lines and I need to retrive cetain informationon the first 2 lines then I have to show all the info bellow. The csv file looks like this

```
Titular,Cuenta #,Moneda,Fecha del reporte,,
MyCompany,123654897,Dollar,26/6/2010,,
,,,,,
Períod,,,,,
From:,31/01/2010,Until:,25/06/2019,,
,,,,,
Date,Description,Númber reference,Débit,Crédit,Balance
31/01/2019,Credito por Intereses,710504251714-50398277,,132.16,"3,073.55"
8/2/2019,Depositos,S9091B19,,"74,258.74","9,722.29"
8/2/2019,ACH Debito,F1999ZV,"8,748.35",,"2,073.55"
14/02/2019,Creditos Varios,F90BRF,,"7,429.77","4,391.32"
18/02/2019,ACH Debito,FT0SMD,"4,824.77",,"3,073.55"
21/02/2019,ACH Credito,F8PH,,"8,000.98","3,673.53"
21/02/2019,Transferencia entre Cuentas,2DMFRG,"7,005.96",,"2,667.57"
22/02/2019,Pago de Comision,R2SHX,20.00,,"5,647.57"
25/02/2019,ACH Credito,FT1905,,"4,083.08","4,490.65"
25/02/2019,Transferencia entre Cuentas,FT254354,"4,437.10",,"3,053.55"
25/02/2019,ACH Credito,ASF455MZQT,,222.15,"3,675.70"
25/02/2019,Transferencia entre Cuentas,GHVF456Q1XLG,"5,536.33",,"5,453.55"
```

I have run some test and been debugging to see the behavior and  ask my self; Do I need to specify the line that Im in , in order for me to retrieve the info? If so, how dow I do it?

heres my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace T_2060_ParserEstadoDeCuenta
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing the csv file");

        List<clsEstadoCuenta> resp = new List<clsEstadoCuenta>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\ztemp\\parseEstcta.csv");
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                /*

                 */
                var campos = lines[i].Split(',');
                clsEstadoCuenta nR = new clsEstadoCuenta();

                nR.NumeroCuenta = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[1])) ? "" : campos[1];
                nR.CodigoPais = 504;
                nR.Banco = "Fichosa";
                nR.Moneda = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[2])) ? "" : campos[2];
                nR.TasaCambio = 24.6;
                var tmpFecha = campos[0].Split('/');
                nR.FechaTransaccion = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[2]), Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[1]), Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[0]));
                nR.Descripcion = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[1])) ? "" : campos[1];
                nR.Referencia = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[2])) ? "" : campos[2];
                nR.Debito = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[4])) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(campos[4]);
                nR.Credito = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[5])) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(campos[5]);
                nR.Payee = "A";




            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("error on line {0} : {1}", i, ex.Message);
                continue;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing has ended, we have {0} rows \n", resp.Count);

        foreach (var item in resp)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(item.NumeroCuenta+"\t" +item.CodigoPais+"\t"+item.Banco+"t"+item.Moneda+"\t"+item.Debito);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class clsEstadoCuenta
    {
        private string _NumeroCuenta;

        public string NumeroCuenta
        {
            get { return _NumeroCuenta; }
            set { _NumeroCuenta = value; }
        }
        private int _CodigoPais;

        public int CodigoPais
        {
            get { return _CodigoPais; }
            set { _CodigoPais = value; }
        }

        private string _Banco;

        public string Banco
        {
            get { return _Banco; }
            set { _Banco = value; }
        }

        private string _Moneda;

        public string Moneda
        {
            get { return _Moneda; }
            set { _Moneda = value; }
        }

        private double _TasaCambio;

        public double TasaCambio
        {
            get { return _TasaCambio; }
            set { _TasaCambio = value; }
        }

        private double _Debito;

        public double Debito
        {
            get { return _Debito; }
            set { _Debito = value; }
        }

        private double _Credito;

        public double Credito
        {
            get { return _Credito; }
            set { _Credito = value; }
        }

        private DateTime _FechaTrasaccion;

        public DateTime FechaTransaccion
        {
            get { return _FechaTrasaccion; }
            set { _FechaTrasaccion = value; }
        }

        private string _Payee;

        public string Payee
        {
            get { return _Payee; }
            set { _Payee = value; }
        }

        private string _Descripcion;

        public string Descripcion
        {
            get { return _Descripcion; }
            set { _Descripcion = value; }
        }

        private string _Referencia;

        public string Referencia
        {
            get { return _Referencia; }
            set { _Referencia = value; }
        }

        private string _CodigoBancario;

        public string CodigoBancario
        {
            get { return _CodigoBancario; }
            set { _CodigoBancario = value; }
        }

        private string _Categoria;

        public string Categoria
        {
            get { return _Categoria; }
            set { _Categoria = value; }
        }

        private string _Sector;

        public string Sector
        {
            get { return _Sector; }
            set { _Sector = value; }
        }

        private double _ValorLocal;

        public double ValorLocal
        {
            get
            {
                _ValorLocal = Credito - Debito;
                return _ValorLocal;
            }
            //set { _ValorLocal = value; }
        }

        private double _ValorDolares;

        public double ValorDolares
        {
            get
            {
                _ValorDolares = ValorLocal / TasaCambio;
                return _ValorDolares;
            }
           // set { _ValorDolares = value; }
        }

        private string _NombreEmpresa;

        public string NombreEmpresa
        {
            get { return _NombreEmpresa; }
            set { _NombreEmpresa = value; }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a [CSV parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+csv+parser) and don't reinvent the wheel. [Here's one](https://github.com/AndrewRissing/GenericParsing), for example.

Comment: A great many CSV parsing libraries exist mainly because parsing CSV files is more complicated than it seems

Comment: Also you could greatly simplify your code. Instead of `private string _NumeroCuento; public string NumeroCuento { get { return _NumeroCuento; } set { _NumeroCuento = value; } }` just write `public string NumeroCuento { get; set; }` (the same for all your other properties).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the formatting of this CSV is not the best, since it mixes numbers with comma and dot and the separation of fields is comma. Still it is possible to work with it, it is only necessary a little logic to reassemble the numbers that will be separated with the `lines.Split(',')`.

Below is the example that lists the data on the screen and adds the values in the `clsEstadoCuenta`.

The logic to mount the broken numbers is this.

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[i]))
     {
         if (campos[i][0] == '\"')
         {
             campos[i] = campos[i] + campos[i + 1];
             campos[i + 1] = "";
             campos[i] = campos[i].Replace("\"","");
         }
     }
```

When he goes through the fields he checks the broken one and if he is he takes the rest of the value in the next field and joins the two.

Here is the complete code below.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadCsv();

        Console.WriteLine("...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ReadCsv()
    {
        string desk = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(@"../../").FullName;
        String path = $@"{desk}\filecsv.csv";
        var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        Console.WriteLine("Parsing the csv file");


        //build header
        var header = csvlines[1].Split(',');

        clsEstadoCuenta nR = new clsEstadoCuenta();
        nR.NumeroCuenta = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header[1])) ? "" : header[1];
        nR.CodigoPais = 504;
        nR.Banco = "Fichosa";
        nR.Moneda = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header[2])) ? "" : header[2];
        nR.TasaCambio = 24.6;


        //build list of data
        foreach (var lines in csvlines.Skip(7))
        {
            var campos = lines.Split(',');

            //mount line
            string newline = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < campos.Count(); i++)
            {
                //Here the numbers that were divided by the Spli (',') 
                //are reassembled and saved in their respective fields.
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[i]))
                {
                    if (campos[i][0] == '\"')
                    {
                        campos[i] = campos[i] + campos[i + 1];
                        campos[i + 1] = "";
                        campos[i] = campos[i].Replace("\"","");
                    }
                }

                newline += $"{campos[i]} \t";
            }

            //puts the values in the clsEstadoCuenta
            var tmpFecha = campos[0].Split('/');
            nR.FechaTransaccion = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[2]), Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[1]), Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[0]));
            nR.Descripcion = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[1])) ? "" : campos[1];
            nR.Referencia = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[2])) ? "" : campos[2];
            nR.Debito = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[4])) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(campos[4]);
            nR.Credito = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[5])) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(campos[5]);
            nR.Payee = "A";

            Console.WriteLine($"{newline}");
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION 2**

This code needs some modifications to work correctly some of the attributes of `clsStateCount.cs` will need to be List and then yes may be `Add()` such as `nR.Debito.Add()`

The class `clsStateCount.cs` will need a constructor that creates the `Lists`.

```
    public clsEstadoCuenta()
    {
        _FechaTrasaccion = new List<DateTime>();
        _Descripcion = new List<string>();
        _Referencia = new List<string>();
        _Payee = new List<string>();
        _Debito = new List<double>();
        _Credito = new List<double>();
        _Payee = new List<string>();
    }
```

Also the `Date`, `Description`, `Númber Reference`, `Débit`, `Crédit` and `Balance` attributes will need to be `List` since they will receive several data.

```
    private List<DateTime> _FechaTrasaccion;
    public List<DateTime> FechaTransaccion
    {
        get { return _FechaTrasaccion; }
        set { _FechaTrasaccion = value; }
    }
```

Here is the complete code for Class:

```
class clsEstadoCuenta
{

    //you will need a builder to create the lists
    public clsEstadoCuenta()
    {
        _FechaTrasaccion = new List<DateTime>();
        _Descripcion = new List<string>();
        _Referencia = new List<string>();
        _Payee = new List<string>();
        _Debito = new List<double>();
        _Credito = new List<double>();
        _Payee = new List<string>();
    }


    //method GetTransactionsNumber() 
    //heck how many items there are in the lists below
    public int GetTransactionsNumber()
    {
        return _FechaTrasaccion.Count;
    }


    //the methods below will be List since it 
    //will receive several values
    private List<DateTime> _FechaTrasaccion;
    public List<DateTime> FechaTransaccion
    {
        get { return _FechaTrasaccion; }
        set { _FechaTrasaccion = value; }
    }

    private List<string> _Descripcion;
    public List<string> Descripcion
    {
        get { return _Descripcion; }
        set { _Descripcion = value; }
    }

    private List<string> _Referencia;
    public List<string> Referencia
    {
        get { return _Referencia; }
        set { _Referencia = value; }
    }

    private List<double> _Debito;
    public List<double> Debito
    {
        get { return _Debito; }
        set { _Debito = value; }
    }

    private List<double> _Credito;
    public List<double> Credito
    {
        get { return _Credito; }
        set { _Credito = value; }
    }

    private List<string> _Payee;
    public List<string> Payee
    {
        get { return _Payee; }
        set { _Payee = value; }
    }



    //private double _ValorLocal;
    //public double ValorLocal
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        _ValorLocal = Credito - Debito;
    //        return _ValorLocal;
    //    }
    //    //set { _ValorLocal = value; }
    //}

    //private double _ValorDolares;
    //public double ValorDolares
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        _ValorDolares = ValorLocal / TasaCambio;
    //        return _ValorDolares;
    //    }
    //    // set { _ValorDolares = value; }
    //}




    private string _NumeroCuenta;
    public string NumeroCuenta
    {
        get { return _NumeroCuenta; }
        set { _NumeroCuenta = value; }
    }
    private int _CodigoPais;
    public int CodigoPais
    {
        get { return _CodigoPais; }
        set { _CodigoPais = value; }
    }

    private string _Banco;
    public string Banco
    {
        get { return _Banco; }
        set { _Banco = value; }
    }

    private string _Moneda;
    public string Moneda
    {
        get { return _Moneda; }
        set { _Moneda = value; }
    }

    private double _TasaCambio;
    public double TasaCambio
    {
        get { return _TasaCambio; }
        set { _TasaCambio = value; }
    }

    private string _NombreEmpresa;
    public string NombreEmpresa
    {
        get { return _NombreEmpresa; }
        set { _NombreEmpresa = value; }
    }

    private string _CodigoBancario;
    public string CodigoBancario
    {
        get { return _CodigoBancario; }
        set { _CodigoBancario = value; }
    }

    private string _Categoria;
    public string Categoria
    {
        get { return _Categoria; }
        set { _Categoria = value; }
    }

    private string _Sector;
    public string Sector
    {
        get { return _Sector; }
        set { _Sector = value; }
    }
}
```

Already the code that reads CSV and what displays I put with separate functions to make it easier to see.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadCsvList();

        Console.WriteLine("...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static void ReadCsvList()
    {
        string desk = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(@"../../").FullName;
        String path = $@"{desk}\filecsv.csv";
        var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(path);


        //build header
        var header = csvlines[1].Split(',');

        clsEstadoCuenta nR = new clsEstadoCuenta();
        nR.NumeroCuenta = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header[1])) ? "" : header[1];
        nR.CodigoPais = 504;
        nR.Banco = "Fichosa";
        nR.Moneda = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header[2])) ? "" : header[2];
        nR.TasaCambio = 24.6;


        //build list of data
        foreach (var lines in csvlines.Skip(7))
        {
            var campos = lines.Split(',');

            //mount line
            string newline = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < campos.Count(); i++)
            {
                //Here the numbers that were divided by the Spli (',') 
                //are reassembled and saved in their respective fields.
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[i]))
                {
                    if (campos[i][0] == '\"')
                    {
                        campos[i] = campos[i] + campos[i + 1];
                        campos[i + 1] = "";
                        campos[i] = campos[i].Replace("\"", "");
                    }
                }

                newline += $"{campos[i]} \t";
            }

            //puts the values in the clsEstadoCuenta
            var tmpFecha = campos[0].Split('/');
            nR.FechaTransaccion.Add(new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[2]), Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[1]), Convert.ToInt32(tmpFecha[0])));
            nR.Descripcion.Add(String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[1]) ? "" : campos[1]);
            nR.Referencia.Add(String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[2]) ? "" : campos[2]);
            nR.Debito.Add(String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[4]) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(campos[4]));
            nR.Credito.Add(String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[5]) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(campos[5]));
            nR.Payee.Add("A");
        }

        //I will only display on the screen in 
        //this function below, it gets cleaner code.
        ListDataCSV(nR);
    }

    private static void ListDataCSV(clsEstadoCuenta data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing the csv file");

        Console.WriteLine($"Conta: {data.NumeroCuenta} \t Pais: {data.CodigoPais} \t Banco: {data.Banco}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Moeda: {data.Moneda} \t\t Cambio: {data.TasaCambio}");

        Console.WriteLine($"");
        Console.WriteLine($"Date \t\t Description \t\t Númber Reference \t\t Débit \t Crédit \t Balance");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.GetTransactionsNumber(); i++)
        {
            var vdata = data.FechaTransaccion[i].ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
            var vdescription = data.Descripcion[i];
            var vreference = data.Referencia[i];
            var vdebito = data.Debito[i];
            var vcredito = data.Credito[i];
            var vpayee = data.Payee[i];

            Console.WriteLine($"{vdata} \t {vdescription} \t\t {vreference} \t\t {vdebito} \t {vcredito} \t {vpayee}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank Alberto for your help.. has helped a lot.. 
I was trying out your suggestion and It worked perfectly. 
Then I tried implementing some of the original code such has trying to add the nR to resp and when  I do a foreach statement in order to show the info it olnly shows 1 row .. 
Im I missing something?

Comment: The part where you list the raw data is configured to begin the loop on line 7 where you have the data. **foreach (var lines in csvlines.Skip(7))**

Comment: Sorry if I did not understand your question.

Comment: I apologies if my question was not clear.
I have a line of code wher I creat a  List<clsEstadoCuenta> resp = new List<clsEstadoCuenta>();
After I parse and save all the required  info I must save the clsEstadoCuenta nR = new clsEstadoCuenta() into resp.

When I do resp.Add(nR) and then I use a foreach statement , Ithought I was going to be shown all info but instead only get 1 row

Comment: I figure it out... the resp.add(nR) was in the wrong place

Comment: I am debugging  the code ... and when I run it , it saves 12 rows of data in to resp but when I print them it  shows this line 
//////
25/02/2019,Transferencia entre Cuentas,GHVF456Q1XLG,"5,536.33",,"5,453.55"
///////
12 times

Comment: I put a Solution 2 at a glance. I understood her placement above and corrected her in the code. @CSharpRookieEd

Comment: Thank you very much Alberto.... your solutions have helped me a lot understand the logic when Parsing. I have been able to parse several csv files that are delimited in different ways with ease

Comment: I'm glad that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you try to separate the cells by splitting ',' but part of the cells contains ',' char. Example: "9,722.29".

Comment: This correctly identifies the error. What could be done to work around it? Probably nothing except generating the data with either a different column delimiter or a different decimal seperator, right?

Comment: The right code is more complex because there can be some variations. Example: '"' in middle of a cell. multiline cell. multiline cell which contain ','. You can find code in Java that deal with this in https://github.com/etuzon/Java-CSV-API

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CSV parser](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) that adheres to [RFC 4180 - Common Format and MIME Type for CSV Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

It is important to understand that the usage of double quotes in your example CSV is likely to handle cases like `"74,258.74"` where the comma is not to be used as a delimiter. As stated by the standard:

> Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
> some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
> at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
> double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:

> ```
>   "aaa","bbb","ccc"
> ```

```
   zzz,yyy,xxx
```

Here is the [Getting Started page](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started) for the most popular compliant parser on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=csv).

Answer (score 0):

this has an answer at [Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net)..

a good way to parse csv in .NET is to use the vb.NET csv parser.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.2

here is more info:
[the type or namespace "TextFieldParser" could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419475/the-type-or-namespace-textfieldparser-could-not-be-found)