# C# Azure Function Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO; reference

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I need to use TextFieldParser from Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO. I used that in past a few times. Now I don't know how to add a needed reference to the Azure function. Framework tab at  Reference Manager(Assemblies) doesn't exist. Even more, when I created a test console application there was also no mentioned tab.
So that way: ["microsoft.visualbasic.fileio does not exist" trying to use TextFieldParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591130/microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-does-not-exist-trying-to-use-textfieldparser/24451534)
doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Reference Microsoft.VisualBasic in a .Net Standard Class Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897920/how-to-reference-microsoft-visualbasic-in-a-net-standard-class-library)

Comment: Unfortunately, instaling nugget package (Microsoft.VisualBasic) is not solving the problem as FileIO is missing at that package