# Need to update certain columns in table from csv file

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I have a csv file and I need to update data in only a few columns in my sql database table.  What is the best way to do this?  I was thinking bulk import however, it will not let me do this without using all of the columns.  I was thinking of using format file, but I wanted to know if this is the most efficient way.

Here is how I was trying it from my C# class:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Update all of the PropertyDefinitions
        /// </summary>
        internal static void InsertPropertyDefinitions()
        {

            //
            //  Define the connection
            //
            SqlConnection insertConnection = null;

            try
            {
                RetryStrategy retryStrategy = new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));
                RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

                retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
                {
                    //
                    //  Try to connect to the database
                    //
                    using (insertConnection = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString))
                    {
                        //
                        //  Open the connection
                        //
                        insertConnection.Open();

                        //
                        //  Get the insert command ready
                        //
                        using (SqlCommand insertRecordCmd = insertConnection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            //
                            // Define the Insert command
                            //
                            insertRecordCmd.CommandText = @"
                            BULK INSERT dbo.[PropertyDefinition] 
                            FROM '//my file path'
                            WITH(
                                    FIRSTROW = 2,
                                    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                                    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'        
                                )
                            ";

                            // Execute the INSERT command
                            insertRecordCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        insertConnection.Close();
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
                //  This is unexpected so display full exception information
                //
                m_Log.WriteLine("Exception while creating table");
                m_Log.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bulk import into a temporary table, and then use just the columns you need from that table to update your own tables.

Comment: That is one option.  The only thing that may prove difficult with this is if I am trying to continuously update this table by republishing the database and creating a new tenant.

Comment: So basically I am going to send the csv file off to another team in our company.  They will update some of the data, send the file back to me and then I want to be able to simply import that data into our current table.

Comment: Why don't you load the CSV into memory and remove the columns you don't want. Then use SqlBulkCopy. The following SO post has an example of creating a DataTable and using SqlBulkCopy. You could modify the code to filter out columns you don't want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759302/upload-csv-file-to-sql-server

Comment: Ok I will try this and see if I can make it work.  Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras This worked.  If you move your comment to Solution I will mark it as 'Answer'.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Tim I put everything into an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommendation would be to put the csv data into memory and filter out the columns you don't want.

The following SO article has an example of how to populate a DataTable from a CSV and use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to bulk insert into SQL Server. You can modify the code to filter out the columns you don't want.

[Upload CSV file to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759302/upload-csv-file-to-sql-server)